# Php processed thumbnail images return black

Tags: php

I have a piece of code that seems to work just fine on processing jpegs on a live server, but processing png's or gif's always give me black images. The funny thing is that on my test server, it processes png's just fine, but no gifs either. This function should work well universally on all mime types, but I guess php is having problems finding the file paths of anything with a file extension other than jpg. Anybody have any ideas on modifiying my function to process png's and gif's correctly, besides switching to python?

```
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
  list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
  $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
  if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
    $w = $h * $scale_ratio; //if original image width is greater than height
  } else {
    $h = $w / $scale_ratio; //if original image height is greater than width
  }
  $img = "";
  $ext = strtolower($ext);
  if ($ext == "gif"){ 
    $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);//gd functions
  } else if($ext =="png"){ 
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
  } else { 
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
  }
  $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);//makes a black rectangle with width and height you specify
  // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
  imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
  if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      imagegif($tci, $newcopy);
  } else if($ext =="png"){ 
    imagepng($tci, $newcopy);
  } else { 
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 84);
  }
}


$file_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; // The file name
$path_suffix = pathinfo($file_name);
$path_ext = $path_suffix['extension'];

$target_file = "uploads/$file_name";
$list_file = "uploads/list_$file_name";
$wmax = 400;
$hmax = 400;
ak_img_resize($target_file, $list_file, $wmax, $hmax, $path_ext);
```

Comment: What's your PHP memory limit? Did you try to upscale that one with ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');

Comment: @Stefan both local and live server are at 128M.

Comment: Do you have set `$path_ext` somewhere else? If not, the script will always use `imagecreatefromjpeg`.

Comment: @jdo Sorry. I should have explained better where $path_ext was coming from. I've edited my post

Comment: Are you sure it correctly recognizes the extension? Try adding `echo $path_ext;exit;` after the `$path_ext = $path_suffix['extension'];` line and test a few jpg, png and gif files to see if the echo outputs the correct extension.

Comment: @CreativeMind First thing I thought. The extension seems to be returning just fine.

Comment: @JohnBowlinger added a revised answer, hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have personally tried your code, didn't touch the function, but modified the bottom part only and it works just fine.
This is how my working script looks like (I am getting the file name from the URL via GET, for debugging):

```
<?php
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
  list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
  $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
  if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
    $w = $h * $scale_ratio; //if original image width is greater than height
  } else {
    $h = $w / $scale_ratio; //if original image height is greater than width
  }
  $img = "";
  $ext = strtolower($ext);
  if ($ext == "gif"){ 
    $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);//gd functions
  } else if($ext =="png"){ 
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
  } else { 
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
  }
  $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);//makes a black rectangle with width and height you specify
  // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
  imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
  if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      imagegif($tci, $newcopy);
  } else if($ext =="png"){ 
    imagepng($tci, $newcopy);
  } else { 
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 84);
  }
}


$file_name = $_GET['img']; // The file name
$path_ext = substr($file_name, -3);

$target_file = $file_name;
$list_file = 'list_' . $file_name;
$wmax = 400;
$hmax = 400;
ak_img_resize($target_file, $list_file, $wmax, $hmax, $path_ext);
?>
```

Note that I tested on several different png, jpg and gif files and they were all resized just fine and should work for u too, unless there is some problem with the original image files themselves.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry. I should have explained better where $path_ext was coming from. I've edited my post

Comment: @JohnBowlinger what about the revised answer? does it still produce black gifs and pngs? I am really curios. Also, if still does, how many different image files did you test it on? Can I download your test images from somewhere to test myself? Thanks.